# Dictionary with dictionaries and lists to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with occupations with titles, occupation code and a list with essential skills with their descriptions.

I'd like to convert this to a pandas dataframe so that I can export it to an excel file

My dictionary looks like this:

```
occupations = 
{ 0:
{'title': 'import export manager', 'code' : '132', 'ess_skills': [{'title': 'title', 'description': 'desciption'},{'title': 'title', 'description': 'desciption'}...]},
1: 
{'title': 'water quality analyst', 'code': '2133', 'ess_skills': [{'title': 'title', 'description': 'description'},{'title': 'title', 'description': 'description'},...]}
...
}
```

I would like to convert this to the following format:

```
    title                  code              title     description
0   import export manager  132    ess_skills title     description
                                             title     description
1   water quality analyst  2133   ess_skills title     description
                                             title     description
```

What would be the best way to create a dataframe with the titles and descriptions of all the skills in individual rows grouped with the title and code of the occupations?

I have no clue on how to incorporate the list of skills within the dataframe, so far I only managed to create a csv file with rows per occupation with their respective title and code and all the list of skills written down as text inside a single cell

Comment: Can you rephrase the question more clearly?

Comment: I added the desired format of the dataframe, does this make the question more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to overcomplicate, nested loops to the rescue:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (
            index,
            data["title"],
            data["code"],
            skill["title"],
            skill["description"],
        )
        for index, data in occupations.items()
        for skill in data["ess_skills"]
    ],
    columns=["index", "title", "code", "skill_title", "skill_description"],
)
```